# jQuery and User Controls

Tags: jquery, user-controls

Question regarding jQuery and User Controls

- I have a series of User Controls and within each user control is a client side method that validates all required fields are validated. I would like to call theses user control's client side methods from the host page when submitting a form. Does anyone have code to do this or lead me to an example.

Thank You,

Comment: Are you asking about ASP.NET User Controls?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a client-side method (ie:JavaScript), then your function should be available in your host page when the user control is included.